# Tap Gesture isn't working. User interaction enabled.

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

Have following view structure:

[image]

Programmatically adding tap gesture rec to Temp lbl:

```
    let tempLblTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainFeedVC.convertDegrees))
    tempLblTap.delegate = self
    tempLblTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tempLblTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tempLblTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.tempLbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.tempLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tempLblTap)
```

but the method `convertDegrees` isn't triggered.

There are also 2 swipe gesture recognizers that are added to the same view:

```
let leftSwipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainFeedVC.showPostPicVC))
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGestureRecognizer)

    let rightSwipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainFeedVC.showUserVC))
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGestureRecognizer)
```

Maybe they are the reason?

Comment: You should be able to have swipe gesture recognizers and a tap gesture recognizer work at the same time. Are there any other views on top of the temperature label?

Comment: nope, no views cover the label.

Comment: Can you try adding the `tempLblTap` gesture recognizer to a different view? If it works, we know there's something wrong with the temp label. If it fails, something is wrong with the gesture recognizer.

Comment: You don't need: `tempLblTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; tempLblTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Comment: @nathan nah, tried adding it to static imageViews, didn't work either.

Comment: can my table view affect upper view with the label?

Comment: Could you add an image of how your view heirarchy looks like?

Comment: @ZonilyJame isn't is the first image in my question?

Comment: tried adding a simple button to this view. The btn isn't being pressed either. 
Can the touch events be swallowed by some other view?

Comment: @Evgeny nope I'm talking about the layers.

Comment: @ZonilyJame how can I show those layers / not sure if i understand which layers you mean.

Answer (score 5):

Found solution:

View that contained my lbl had its `userInteractionEnabled` unchecked in storyboards. 
So, when adding gesture recognizers to labels, images or simply adding buttons, always check that all parent views has its `userInteractionEnabled` to `true`.